# Angularjs scope update issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs. Facing a problem like below
My markup is like:

```
<div class="data-list">
    <ul ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:orderProp | filter:query">
        <li><a ng-click="update(client)"  data={{client.id}} href="#">{{client.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clientId">
    {{clientId}}
</div>
```

And my controller is like:

```
function ClientListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/dummy-data/clients.json', {
        cache: false
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.clients = data.clients;
    });

    $scope.activeClient = {};
    $scope.update = function (selectedClient) {
        $scope.activeClient = angular.copy(selectedClient);
        console.log($scope.activeClient);
    }

    console.log("after click");
    console.log($scope.activeClient);
    // for sorting list 
    $scope.orderProp = '-numberOfUsers';
}
```

I want when user click "Client Name", `{{clientId}}` would be updated, but the scope updates it self. And return `{}` (blank object).

How I can get the {{clientId}} after clicking the clientName?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You controller does not have any property like `clientId` and you `ng-repeat` is scoped only to the `<ul>` tags.

Change

```
<div class="clientId">
   {{clientID}}
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="clientId">
   {{activeClient}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `{{clientId}}` with `{{activeClient.id}}`

I made a simple example based on your code.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ClientListCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="client in clients">
            <li><a ng-click="update(client)" href="#">{{client.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clientId"><br/>
            Client id: {{activeClient.id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function ClientListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.clients = [
        {"id":1, "name": "client1"},
        {"id":2, "name": "client2"},
        {"id":3, "name": "client3"},
        {"id":4, "name": "client4"},
        {"id":5, "name": "client5"},
        {"id":6, "name": "client6"}
    ];

    $scope.activeClient = {};
    $scope.update = function(selectedClient) {
        $scope.activeClient = angular.copy(selectedClient);
    }
}
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bDQuL/) jsfiddle

Comment: Hey,thanks for the jsfiddle,but in my code its not wroking . my markup is like http://jsfiddle.net/YcP9S/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/YcP9S/1/ is your markup (i add only ng-app div) with my js. It works fine. Check your js or paste it in jsfiddle to have a look